# Returning PromiseValue when creating an object

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Ok so i've searched around and found nothing related to this problem.

My problem is something like this ->

I create an object (push into array) with some info taken from an api. After getting the info from the api i need to call yet another API to get further information on users. Since there are multiple keys for users i'd like to be able to set them inline with a simple function.

I'm doing something like this ->

```
_item.push({
    Author: setPeople(item.Author.Title),
    Title: item.Title,
    ....
    Requester: setPeople(item.Requester.Title
})
```

At the moment i am getting the promise set(entirely) and not the `PromiseValue`. I know you usually do something like `setPeople(name).then(() => {})` however that is not working in my object (sets the key too fast).

Any tip on how i should approach this?

Updating with more code.

```
export const retrieveIrfItems = async (spId) => {
    let spQuery = "SITE" + SpQueryExtend1 + spQueryExpand;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let _items = [];
        axiosApi.get(SiteUrl + spQuery).then((response) => {
            //console.log(response.data.d);
            return response.data.d;
        }).then(async (item) => {
            //let requesterSP = setPeople()
            const createSPUser = async (user) => {
                let spUser;
                console.log("User prop is");
                console.log(user);
                setPeople(user).then((item) => {
                    spUser = item;
                });
                return spUser;
            }

                _item.push({
        Author: setPeople(item.Author.Title),
        Title: item.Title,
        ....
        Requester: setPeople(item.Requester.Title
    })
```

Ignore the unused function, i'm still doing tests to find a way for this problem.

Found the fix thanks to comments.

Using async/await wouldnt help me since i'd still get promise pending or undefined. What i had to use is ->

`Requester: await setPeople(item.Requester.Title).then((user) => { return user }),`

Using that in my object seems to work, but my question is...how good is this approach? If there are lots of fields with this behaviour (currently 5), wouldnt that slow down the page by...a lot ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Did you try using the async-await flow?

Comment: I doubt its a duplicate since the context is different. Can't use async since my object is created in the `.then()` of the first API call. Doesnt seem like a good practice (also its setting it as undefined if i do that).

Comment: @asiby that actually worked (with a bit of a workaround. Thanks for the idea. Now i wonder how it will behave when there are lots of items/fields..

Comment: No that wouldn't be practical .. You can `await Promise.all()`. Also note that wrapping `axiosApi.get()` in `new Promise()` is an anti-pattern when you can `return axiosApi.get()`

Comment: How would i be able to use await Promise.All() in my object tho'? Since there are different promises (I'm calling setPeople for each field).

Comment: is your `createSPUser` usefull ? what if the purpose of `retrieveIrfItems` ? should it return your `_item` array ?

Comment: `createSPUser` is there just for testing purposes (not used at the moment). 
`retrieveIrfItems` returns the `_items` array on component load in react as such -> `retrieveIrfItems(this.props.selected.Id).then((item) => {
            this.props.setDefaultFields(item[0]);
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should try something like that :

```
export const retrieveIrfItems = async (spId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let spQuery = "SITE" + SpQueryExtend1 + spQueryExpand;
    let _items = [];
    try{
      const axiosApiItem = await axiosApi.get(SiteUrl + spQuery);
      const item = axiosApiItem.data.d;
      _item.push({
        Author: await setPeople(item.Author.Title),
        Title: item.Title,
        ...
        Requester: await setPeople(item.Requester.Title)
      });
      return resolve(_items);
    }catch(e){
      return reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Async / await is a way to consume async `Promise` functions. The `async` keyword tells the javascript compiler that this function will consume one or more asynchronous functions. The `await` keyword tells the compiler that the next function call is asynchronous and returns a promise.

In your code, your first `then()` function should return a promise which is not the case, that's why the second `then()` can't be reached.

Also, in your code, your `new Promise` doesn't return anything. When you create a new Promise, you have to end it by calling `resolve()` or `reject`.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thats pretty much how i modified my code. I already had `resolve()` but it was in another `then()` (there's one more and my first `then()` was doing `return _items`. Thing is, it works and all, but isnt this a bit heavy on performance ? (Fact is there are about 3 api calls for a single item object and no way to work around this unfortunately). EDIT: Takes about 4 seconds to populate my form with API data with 3 people fields (i'll have around 7-9) so it sounds like 1 second per field.

Comment: there's a lot of different ways to achieve that king of calls, with `async` library, `rxjs` library, ... which have each goods and bads. In your case, you only use standard javascript functions so I don't think it's the worse way to do that. The only way for you to increase performances would be to add a function on the server API to perform all the requests locally then send you the final result.

Comment: Ok so no library can help with the speed. I'll just try to minify my app as much as i can then. Thanks!